# Variables values remain saved after closing and opening the same page

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, web-deployment

I'm not sure if I addressed this question correctly. How my pages should work is that every time you login, that user object is stored on the global page as a static variable. That way I can call it from any page. That works fine. When testing locally, works like a charm. But when I test my site from IIS, remotely, works fine. But if I close the page and call it again, that user object stays with the same value. I'm kinda new to web application deployment. The way I deployed the site was taking all of the files referenced in the solution explorer and dumped them in the application directory on IIS. I know there's other ways, but I tried others and this one was the only one that worked.

**Pt2**: Gave it some thought and this also came to mind. If I implement sessions instead of static variables for storing user class object, will this work if two users try logging?

PS. Would test it myself, but still haven't changed my code to use sessions instead of static variables.

Also, I'm still a junior and I've been given full responsibility of a project cause the lead developer bailed. I'm baffled by this due to the fact that I've only managed pages. Never have I done a full system from scratch. Any help is gladly appreciated.

Please explain your answer and thanks

Comment: Try disposing/destroying the object when your page is closed and or when user logs out or your page is closed unexpectedly. That way every time you will have a fresh object to start with and it will end with the page close event.

Comment: Why don't you use session variables ? Is there any special purpose for using static variables in Global class ?

Comment: @pravprab Can't use session because this object has quite a few members.

Comment: @MattMurdock, I'll read up on page lifecycle and try your suggestion. I thought this was done automatically.

Comment: @pravprab, I've used session and just realized you could store a class object inside. I'll probably do that.

Comment: @MattMurdock - If he is using a static variable this still doesn't solve the bigger problem of concurrency. Any thread can update that value, so you could get into all kinds of nasty issues.

Comment: @Josh - That it is. Static variables are risky.

Comment: You can store in Session the object directly (e.g. `Session["myObject"] = myStaticObject`. The fact that it has a lot of members is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So let me walk you back off the cliff here.

A global static in a web application is generally a bad idea, especially when dealing with user data. This is because [static variables are only defined in one spot per AppDomain](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx#Anchor_0).

> Only one copy of a static member exists, regardless of how many instances of the class are created.

This means that **ALL** threads will have access to the same variable. And on a web app with multiple concurrent users, this is bad news.

A much better option is to use some sort of [Session](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx) or [Cache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache(v=vs.110).aspx), but just know that even those have limitations if you are running this in a server farm.

### UPDATE:

If you want your value to be available on every page, then you can always create a base page object with a property on it that simply reads/writes to session. It's an easy way to encapsulate the data.

```
public MyObject {
  get { return (MyObject)Session["MyObject_key"]; }
  set { Session["MyObject_key"] = value; }
}
```

Comment: I've used session variables, but wasn't aware that you could store a class object in them.

Comment: What would you suggest? how could I store this user object and making it accessible on every page with out constantly querying it.

Comment: @chelo666 - You can store anything you want in there. Just remember that if you are running in a server farm environment, then you will need some other kind of session provider besides the InProc session... either that or you will need to make sure your Load Balancer is using sticky sessions. Otherwise you can get bounced to a different server in between requests and not have your data available.

Comment: @chelo666 At the end Session is nothing but Dictionary<string,object> so yes you can actually put anything as a value. So `Session["user"] = userObj`.

Comment: @chelo666 - See my updated answer.

Comment: @Josh, I see... Well it's a medium size site and I'm almost curtain they only have one server cause last week that server got busted and no work could be done. No emails, no external access

Comment: @nvartak, yeah I figured something like that. Gotta run some test just to make sure everything is stored. anywhere I need to call it just cast back to user obj.

Comment: @chelo666 - Yes, you will always need to cast it. To be safe, you should probably use `Session["blah"] as MyObject` to ensure that if it is null it won't throw an exception.

Comment: If what's in the session under the `blah` key *isn't* a `MyObject`, I'd rather the code blow up close to where that assumption is violated with a cast exception rather than inject a null reference exception to occur later in execution.

Comment: Using sessions fixed all of my problems. Thank you very much!